# Is it a good idea to create Poco::ActiveMethod dynamically in an application and allowed to destroy once the routine is completed?

Tags: c++, poco

In my application I create may Poco::ActiveMethod objects dynamically for incoming request processing. However noticed that those were not cleaned properly. Therefore application thread count increases with the requests.

How should I cleanup them? I noticed some exceptions in destroying Poco::ActiveMethod objects even if the corresponding routine is already completed.

Please advice.